# listview with CheckedTextView not working properly

Tags: java, android, listview

I have implemented a list View with CheckedTextView . When I am selecting a particular row and clicking on checkbox then checkbox becomes invisible. Also sometimes any other row get selected.I want to select multiple items. 
please help...
List_row Layout is..

```
 <CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/service_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:checked= "false"
   >
```

CustomListView is:

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;

   public class CustomListView extends ArrayAdapter {

 //to reference the Activity
   private final Activity context;
   String value;

//to store the list items
   private final String[] nameArray;
   CheckedTextView nameTextField;
   public CustomListView(Activity context, ArrayList nameArra) {

    super(context, R.layout.row_list_view, nameArrayParam);
    this.context = context;
    this.nameArray = nameArrayParam;
}

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
   {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list_view, null, true);

    //this code gets references to objects in the listview_row.xml file
     nameTextField = (CheckedTextView) 
      rowView.findViewById(R.id.service_name);

   //this code sets the values of the objects to values from the arrays
    nameTextField.setText(nameArray[position]);


  // perform on Click Event Listener on CheckedTextView
    nameTextField.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.v("customList",";clicked row is " + 
            nameTextField.getText().toString());

            if (nameTextField.isChecked()) {
           // set check mark drawable and set checked property to false
                value = "un-Checked";
                nameTextField.setCheckMarkDrawable(R.color.colorAccent);
                nameTextField.setChecked(false);
            } 
else {

// set check mark drawable and set checked property to true
                value = "Checked";

                nameTextField.setChecked(true);
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return rowView;

}
```

In my MainActivity.java, I have used listView setOnItemClickListener

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                long arg3) {

            selected_Item = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                        Toast.makeText(AskForService.this, "Clicked item is" + selected_Item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

After implementing these code I can see -

1. ListView with checked TextView
2. ListView Can Scroll showing all the list items
3. on clicking a particular row..listview click listener is called and showing the Toast but checkbox becomes white(invisible) and sometimes another row get selected...Please help

Answer (score 0):

Create a model class which contains a flag "isChecked" and set the data according to the model inside adapter

This link might be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40285759/8770539

Answer (score 0):

Use an arraylist to **`store checked item's position`**.

call **`notifyDataSetChanged()`** for onclick()

Use this,

```
    if(list.contains(position)) {
         nameTextField.setChecked(true);
    }
    else {
         nameTextField.setChecked(false);
    }
    nameTextField.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(list.contains(position))
            {
                list.remove(position);
            }
            else
            {
                list.add(position);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
    });
```